# Firebase Database

Tags: kotlin, firebase-database

После авторизации пользователя загружает объекты из Firebase Database. Всё бы хорошо, только делает это 2-3 раза из 10. Приходится обновлять Activity. В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

```
private lateinit var myAdapter: AdapterNote
private lateinit var colorDrawableBackground: ColorDrawable
private lateinit var deleteIcon: Drawable
private var items = ArrayList<Note>()
private var user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
private val ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(user!!.uid)
private var firebaseUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
private lateinit var dbRef:DatabaseReference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val rv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv)

    dbRef=ref.ref

    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager?

    showAllNoteDB()

    //updateList()

    sortDate(items)

    items.reverse()

    Log.i("List Notes", items.toString())

    myAdapter = AdapterNote(items, object : AdapterNote.CallBack {

        override fun onItemClicked(item: Note) {

            var intent = Intent(applicationContext, NoteActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(NoteActivity.ID_TEXT, item.id)
            intent.putExtra(NoteActivity.NOTE,item)
            intent.putExtra(NoteActivity.INTENT_STATUS, true)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
    })
```

Метод showAllNote()

```
private fun showAllNoteDB() {
    ref.addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if(p0!!.exists()) {
                for(i in p0.children){
                    val noteItem=i.getValue(Note::class.java)
                    items.add(noteItem!!)
                }
            }
        }

    })
}
```

Грешу на медленный интернет и может стоит в фоновом потоке вызывать?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена. Загрузка данных производится в фоновом потоке и в конце вызывается `notifyDataSetChanged()`.